# What is the best way to implement a FSA/FSM in Java

Tags: java, spell-checking, state-machine

I have a big finite state automaton with like 50 states and each state has avg. 3-4 transitions to other states. So I don't think the "state pattern" is suitable for this. This FSM tends to be a spellchecker and morphological analyzer for some agglutinative language.

What is the best way to implement a FSA/FSM in Java or should I use an open source library. Since natural languages are not regular (have exception cases), is there a way to make this implementation flexible for such situations.

Thanks

Comment: If its a spell checker then probably you can make use of bloom filter instead of using fsm.

Comment: @emil thanks for comment. It is not only going to check the word for correctness but also analyze it to its root and suffixes.

Comment: @hrzafer: It seem's like [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be a good data structure for you.A [google search](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=trie+google&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) would give you some good implementations of trie.

Comment: @hrzafer: Also check out this [blog on suffix trees](http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/).

Comment: It seems like a great post for me. I'll study it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be straightforward to implement this as a directed, labelled graph.  Perhaps there are graph libraries for Java that would be appropriate for this too, however I have no experience with them so I will leave it to others to make specific recommendations.